Upgrade Windows 2019 to Windows 2022 on a server that has SharePoint Server installed
I have a problem with upgrading OS where I have Sharepoint 2019 server (Single-Server Farm) with DB on same server. What is the correct procedure to do this?
I have an idea to convert Single-Server Farm to another role so I can join the new server and transfer the roles.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
I have try to do upgrade of Windows on that server but it didn't work. I have installed a new VM with Sharepoint 2019 an try to joined to farm. No success.

https://petri.com/windows-server-2022-series-part-3-upgrading-final-3-servers/
According to the information provided in the link, it seems that a direct upgrade of Windows Server is possible. I'll give it a try!

I have upgraded OS to Windows Server 2022 and when I tried to access Sharepoint I got a new error.
ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
Solution for this was adding two registry keys.
Navigate:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters
Add 2 new REG_DWORD values, EnableHttp2Tls and EnableHttp2Cleartext
Set both values to 0.
Reboot the server
It seems that everything is working after the upgrade.
Thank you for reading!

To upgrade the operating system on a server running SharePoint 2019 with a single-server farm and the database on the same server, you should start the upgrade process immediately. You can proceed directly with the OS upgrade.
